# cmake: how to separately compile production code and test code

Tags: unit-testing, cmake, googletest

I read [this brilliant tutorial](http://www.kaizou.org/2014/11/gtest-cmake.html) about how to integrate Google Test with CMake. The outline of the project there looks like this:

```
+-- CMakeLists.txt
+-- main
|    +-- CMakeLists
|    +-- main.cpp
|
+-- test
|    +-- CMakeLists.txt
|    +-- testfoo
|       +-- CMakeLists.txt
|       +-- main.cpp
|       +-- testfoo.h
|       +-- testfoo.cpp
|       +-- mockbar.h
|
+-- libfoo
|    +-- CMakeLists.txt
|    +-- foo.h
|    +-- foo.cpp
|
+-- libbar
     +-- CMakeLists.txt
     +-- bar.h
     +-- bar.cpp
```

(For the interested, the entire code of this example project can be checked out from [here](https://github.com/kaizouman/gtest-cmake-example))

The top-level CMakeLists.txt contains (among others) the statements `enable_testing()` and `add_subdirectory(test)`. Compiling and running test cases works perfectly with this setup, simply by running

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make
make test
```

But how would I compile this project into production code, i.e. only the components `test`, `libfoo` and `libbar`, without all the unit tests?

Should I make the statements `enable_testing()` and `add_subdirectory(test)` somehow dependent on some build configuration variables? Or what's the best practice for this?

Comment: You can make CMake command calls only dependent on the build configuration in single configuration `make` environments. I'm wondering if you know about [`EXCLUDE_FROM_DEFAULT_BUILD_<CONFIG>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/EXCLUDE_FROM_DEFAULT_BUILD_CONFIG.html) target property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To build the tests only on request, I do it in this way:

1. Add an option `option(BUILD_TEST "Build the unit tests" ON)`
2. Include the test subdirs only in case BUILD_TEST is on

`if(BUILD_TEST)
    add_subdirectory(test)
endif()`

In your case you can modify this to testfoo.

As you asked for production, you can use the following instead to build in debug mode only:

`if("${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" STREQUAL "Debug")
    add_subdirectory(test)
endif()`

Answer (score 1):

What I do is to make a custom macro for unit test creation which does this:

```
set_target_properties(${NAME} PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test)
```

Then your tests will end up in a special directory (`test`) instead of the regular one (usually `bin`).  Then for production you just copy the regular directory without the test directory.

Comment: So you say that you generally always build both production and test code? Ok, the more I think about it, the more I agree with it (though in this case building the test code might sometimes be a bit heavy, as it also downloads and builds googletest - but there are solutions to that). Actually the separation to different output directories is done already. I'm not quite sure what advantage the command you posted would bring.